# Show that $f_n(x):=\frac{e^{x/n}}{n}$ converges uniformly to $0$

Tags: real-analysis

The sequence of functions $(f_n):[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x):=e^{x/n}/n$ converges uniformly to $0$.

I can show pointwise convergence by choosing an appropriate $N\in\mathbb{N}$ which depends on $x$ and $\epsilon$, but how can I show uniform convergence? i.e. getting rid of the dependence on $x$?

Comment: Yes. For any $\;n\in\Bbb N,\,x\in [0,1]\;,\;\;\frac{e^{x/n}}n\le\frac{e^{1/n}}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f_n(x) -0| \le \frac{1}{n}e^{1/n} \le 3 \frac{1}{n}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and all $n$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Hmm... do you mean that $e^{1/n}\le 1$ for all $n$?

Comment: $e^{1/n} \leq 3$ should work.